# Is it possible to customise the look and feel of IBM MobileFirst App Center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I need to know whether its possible to customise the look and feel of IBM Mobile First App Center. Like adding our own branding image and changing the ui style of the App Center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to the Application Center Management Console - you cannot alter its UI because it is part of a .war file. You could potentially open this .war file, edit the files and re-deploy it. But this is an action not supported by IBM.

If you are referring to the Application Center Installer application that you install on the end-user device, yes, you can customize its look & feel, as you have the project source code. Feel free to alter its UI however you'd like. However if you alter its functionality, this will not be supported.

Comment: thanks. Can u point me to a link where i can download the project source code for IBM App center mobile application ?

Comment: What do you mean? As an IBM customer you already have said sources as part of the package you have download. Consult your documentation.

Comment: I can only find the link to download IBMApplicationCenter.apk file from the server from this link : https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/moving-production/distributing-mobile-applications-application-center/#clients  and i couldn't find any links regarding downloading the source code

Comment: The project and its source code is part of the package you download. You do not download it separately.